# How to install mod_wsgi for apache2.4 with python 3.6 in centos?

Tags: apache

I am a new to web development.I have created Django(-v 2.2) web application and I want to deploy it on my linux server(OS Centos).After installation apache2, when I was going to install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3, it says that no package available. Is there different name for libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 for OS Centos?

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to install mod_wsgi directly into the python3 package using pip3.
pip3 install mod_wsgi
If you install mod_wsgi into the OS, it could cause conflict and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `apache2-dev` installed?
Also, for mod_wsgi it is better to go the CMMI path (configure-make-make install) in order to compile it with the correct version and load it in Apache as a module. This worked for me on Debian VPS:

To do so,

```
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.6.5.tar.gz

tar xvfz 4.6.5.tar.gz 

cd mod_wsgi-4.6.5 

whereis apxs 
whereis python3 

./configure --with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.5 

make 

sudo make install
```

Double check the path for apxs and python, and run make install as sudo.

When it’s all ready, check the last line of prompt results, as there will be a path to a file: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

To cleanup after installation, run:

`make clean`

If you need to build the module for a different version of Apache, you should run:

`make distclean`

If you have a  httpd.conf file, you should edit and add this line:

LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so

If not, create it and paste that line, and edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf.`  file, by adding this line:

`Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

You don't need that file to configure apache, but you can create it if other software relies on it being there.

You should restart Apache and check the log 
`sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`

as there should be a line that says: 
`Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations`